Invoke-WebRequest fails at TLS Server Certificate Request with ECC Certificate
I have a following scenario:

We have created some self signed CA Certificates (RSA and ECCC variants) that are set up on the server for TLS Auth.
We have Created some client certificates for test purposes. Both CAs have 2 certificates: valid and one revoked by CRL. CRL was also provided to the server.
Now for the test we verify everything with our GO Client, Curl (not the PS Alias!) and Invoke-WebRequest.
RSA: everything works fine. Valid certificate gets HTTP OK, revoked one -> revoked error
ECC: Curl and GO client work as expected. PowerShell's (Core 7.4.1) Invoke-WebRequest fails. I analyzed the TLS 1.2 communication with Wireshark and have found that, the server sends a Certificate request with a list of known CAs, which corresponds with RFC 5246 - 7.4.X. The client must now provide a client certificate to match one of those CAs, or send an empty certificate message (RFC 5246 - 7.4.6). That is exactly what is happening here, also the server correctly provides known CAs.

Why can't Invoke-WebRequest find a client certificate for ECC CA, what am i missing?
Invokation example:
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "URI" -TimeoutSec 10 -Certificate "PathToCert"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "URI" -TimeoutSec 10 -Certificate (Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath "PathToCert")

System: Windows 10
ECC Params: sha512ECDSA, ECDH_P521
P.S. Curl seems to work differently in general and always sends the provided certificate, even if it does not match any CA's requested by the server

Are you running on same machine with same account?  Certificate has to be loaded in both the machine and the user stores.  Curl maybe using OpenSSH.  The certificate has an encryption mode that may be reason for error.  TLS 1.2 will not support a TLS 1.3 encryption mode.  See Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

All tests were made from the same client. No certificates were added to any stores on the client. It did work for RSA certs like this.

I said ACCOUNT?  It could be the account doesn't have certificate.  What you are seeing in Wireshark is the Machine negotiation, but the certificate gets used in the user account.  Also it could be mitigations.  See Cipher section on following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security.

All Tests were made from the same machine and the same account. The certificate is passed directly to the PowerShell command from file system so it is not necessary in user the store, what also corresponds to Invoke-WebRequest docs.
What does the "depends on mitigations" part mean?
As far as i can tell server and client have successfully chosen AES GCM as a cipher suite, which according to your link is not affected by mitigations.

See what following returns : $cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath "PathToCert"; Write-Host $cert.GetType();

@jdweng It returns System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2

Try following.  I suspect you may have older PS installed and not working with X509Certificate2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1329533/difference-between-invoke-webrequest-httpclient-cl  Or maybe the timeout is too short.

I am using PS Core 7.4.1. (older PS, 5.1, is also installed) and i have tried to increase the timeout but i do not think that it is the cause as i get an answer in under 2 seconds on average.
Is there a way to check which Version is used?

Does code work without the certificate option which will use a default certificate?  TLS only the names of certificate is passed not the actual key.  Could you have a different certificate with same name installed on client and server?  What OS is being used on client and server?  PS uses OS for TLS.  Maybe Curl and GO are using OpenSSH.  5246 is obsolete https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata/rfc5246.  I suspect the encryption mode in certificate is old and is being rejected.  See my link in my response Apr 12 12:47.  There is table showing TLS version and Encryption modes.

I think i have found something, with your help.
According to your link DHE-ECDSA only works with TLS 1.3. I was making TLS 1.2 calls with PowerShell. If i add "-SslProtocol Tls13" parameter, than it also fails, but the use of "$error[0].exception.innerexception" shows System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090331): -> client and server do not have same algorithm. Powershell does use native system dependencies, while curl uses OpenSSL and GO brings own cryptography modules.
Client OS: Windows
Server OS: Linux

Exception just means the connection did not complete.  Could mean you have an older OS that doesn't support the encryption mode.  I thought certificate has to be loaded in windows in both machine and user storage.  The OS first establishes the TLS encryption using machine storage and then actual data gets encrypted with the user storage.  Is the exact same certificate being used?  Is private key the same? Is padding mode the same?  Do you have all Windows updates installed?

Try 7.4.2 : https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases

Same error with 7.4.2

So i have analyzed the communication with wireshark again and have found out that, the go client uses TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 cipher. Powershell has "Get-TlsCipherSuite" cmdlet, which shows available suites and the output contains TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384...

Do you see the HTTP Request after the TLS?  Compare the working wireshark against non working and see where first difference occurs.  Then look at RFC 8446 : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446  HTTP uses TCP for transport layer.  There should be a [FIN] when TCP connection closes.  See if the client or server sends the [FIN].  Then we would know if the client or server found the error.  Each HTTP consists of one or more TCP datagrams.

Unfortunately our test certificates have expired (both client and ca) and there is no possibility to create new ones, as we do not have control over the endpoint and the responsible organization would ask for billing. We have decided to use RSA for the time being and reevaluate this topic at a later point in time. Thank you all for help. If i manage to find out more i will let you know
